# Flush matrix entries to Left side

Tags: amsmath, matrices

So I have the following codes

```
\begin{dmath}
  P_1=\left\{\begin{matrix}
{P_E} + K(1 - {e^{ - rT}}) - S(1 - {e^{ - \delta T}})\\
- KI(0,T,S,{B_{11}},{b_{11}}, - 1,r)\\
+ SI(0,T,S,{B_{11}},{b_{11}},1,\delta )\;\text{if }\;S > {B_{11}}\\
K - S\quad \text{if } \;S \le {B_{11}}
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{dmath}


\begin{dmath}
P_2=\left\{\begin{matrix}
{P_E} + K(1 - {e^{ - rT}}) - S(1 - {e^{ - \delta T}})\\
- KI(0,T/2,S,{B_{21}},{b_{21}}, - 1,r)\\
+ SI(0,T/2,S,{B_{21}},{b_{21}},1,\delta )\\
- KI(T/2,T,S,{B_{21}},{b_{21}}, - 1,r)\\
+ SI(T/2,T,S,{B_{21}},{b_{21}},1,\delta )\quad \text{if }\;S > {B_{22}}\\
K - S\quad \text{if }\;S \le {B_{22}}.
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{dmath}

\begin{dmath}   
P_3=\left\{\begin{matrix}
{P_E} + K(1 - {e^{ - rT}}) - S(1 - {e^{ - \delta T}})\\
- KI(0,T/3,S,{B_{33}},{b_3}, - 1,r)\\
+ SI(0,T/3,S,{B_{33}},{b_3},1,\delta )\\
- KI(T/3,2T/2,S,{B_{32}},{b_{32}}, - 1,r)\\
+ SI(T/3,2T/3,S,{B_{32}},{b_{32}},1,\delta )\\
- KI(2T/3,T,S,{B_{31}},{b_{31}}, - 1,r)\\
+ SI(2T/3,T,S,{B_{31}},{b_{31}},1,\delta )\quad \text{if }\;S > {B_{33}}\\
K - S\quad \text{if }\;S \le {B_{33}}.\\
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{dmath}
```

Unfortunetly this produces the following picture

[image]

I want it to look more like this [image]

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Have you tried to use a `cases` environment, possibly with an `aligned` inside?

Comment: no I have not, first time ive heard of it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the `cases` environment from the `amsmath` package. I don't know where your `matrix` and `dmath` come from.

I think the extra spacing you experience is due to the `\left\{`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{equation}
P_{1}=
\begin{cases}
P_E + K(1 - {e^{ - rT}}) - S(1 - {e^{ - \delta T}})\\
{}- KI(0,T,S,{B_{11}},{b_{11}}, - 1,r)\\
{}+ SI(0,T,S,{B_{11}},{b_{11}},1,\delta )\quad\text{if}\; S > {B_{11}}\\
K - S\quad \text{if}\; S \le {B_{11}}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
P_{2}=
\begin{cases}
P_E + K(1 - {e^{ - rT}}) - S(1 - {e^{ - \delta T}})\\
{}- KI(0,T/2,S,{B_{21}},{b_{21}}, - 1,r)\\
{}+ SI(0,T/2,S,{B_{21}},{b_{21}},1,\delta )\\
{}- KI(T/2,T,S,{B_{21}},{b_{21}}, - 1,r)\\
{}+ SI(T/2,T,S,{B_{21}},{b_{21}},1,\delta )\quad \text{if}\; S > {B_{22}}\\
K - S\quad \text{if}\; S \le {B_{22}}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
P_{3}=
\begin{cases}
P_E + K(1 - {e^{ - rT}}) - S(1 - {e^{ - \delta T}})\\
{}- KI(0,T/3,S,{B_{33}},{b_3}, - 1,r)\\
{}+ SI(0,T/3,S,{B_{33}},{b_3},1,\delta )\\
{}- KI(T/3,2T/2,S,{B_{32}},{b_{32}}, - 1,r)\\
{}+ SI(T/3,2T/3,S,{B_{32}},{b_{32}},1,\delta )\\
{}- KI(2T/3,T,S,{B_{31}},{b_{31}}, - 1,r)\\
{}+ SI(2T/3,T,S,{B_{31}},{b_{31}},1,\delta )\quad \text{if}\; S > {B_{33}}\\
K - S\quad \text{if}\; S \le {B_{33}}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: to be precise they are not aligned p1, p2 , p3 but anyway thanx

Comment: nvm I solved it.

Comment: You may want to prefix the `-` and `+` symbols at the beginnings of lines with `{}`, to make TeX interpret them as binary rather than as unary operators.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly your intent, you are after something like this:

[image: Output of the following code]

The code:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{mathtools}



\begin{document}

It's always best to start with some text.
\begin{align}
    P_{1} &=
        \begin{cases*}
            \begin{aligned}[b]
                P_{E} &+ K(1 - e^{-rT}) - S(1 - e^{-\delta T})\\
                & - KI(0,T,S,B_{11},b_{11},-1,r)\\
                & + SI(0,T,S,B_{11},b_{11},1,\delta )
            \end{aligned}
            & if $S > B_{11}$, \\
            K - S & if $S \le B_{11}$.
        \end{cases*}
    \\
    P_{2} &=
        \begin{cases*}
            \begin{aligned}[b]
                P_{E} &+ K(1 - e^{-rT}) - S(1 - e^{-\delta T})\\
                & - KI(0,T/2,S,B_{21},b_{21},-1,r)\\
                & + SI(0,T/2,S,B_{21},b_{21},1,\delta )\\
                & - KI(T/2,T,S,B_{21},b_{21},-1,r)\\
                & + SI(T/2,T,S,B_{21},b_{21},1,\delta )
            \end{aligned}
            & if $S > B_{22}$, \\
            K - S & if $S \le B_{22}$.
        \end{cases*}
    \\
    P_{3} &=
        \begin{cases*}
            \begin{aligned}
                P_{E} &+ K(1 - e^{-rT}) - S(1 - e^{-\delta T})\\
                & - KI(0,T/3,S,B_{33},b_{3},-1,r)\\
                & + SI(0,T/3,S,B_{33},b_{3},1,\delta )\\
                & - KI(T/3,2T/2,S,B_{32},b_{32},-1,r)\\
                & + SI(T/3,2T/3,S,B_{32},b_{32},1,\delta )\\
                & - KI(2T/3,T,S,B_{31},b_{31},-1,r)\\
                & + SI(2T/3,T,S,B_{31},b_{31},1,\delta )
            \end{aligned}
            & if $S > B_{33}$, \\
            K - S & if $S \le B_{33}$.
        \end{cases*}
\end{align}
Text after the equations.

\end{document}
```

Points to note:

- The `mathtools` package (which automatically loads `amsmath` too)
  provides a `cases*` enviroment that typesets the second column
  in text—as opposed to math—mode.  Other choices are also available:
  see p. 18 of the manual of the `mathtools` package.
- I’ve used an `aligned` environment, with optional argument `[b]`,
  to wrap long formulas that (I repeat, if I understand correctly)
  belong to the same logical branch.
- I’ve also removed a lot of superfluous braces.
- As a “feature” (;-) , the last equation shows, by way of example,
  what purpose the `[b]` argument serves…